# Xvarnish (cachewall) with mod_pagespeed

Tags: apache, cpanel, varnish, mod-pagespeed

There is an issue where I have a cpanel server with cachewall (Xvarnish used to be called) and mod_pagspeed installed.

Cachewall/Xvarnish has https support enabled.

The issue is that even though the header of the website is showing that both Cachewall and modpagespeed is running, I'm getting flooded with this in my apache error log:

```
[Mon Jul 03 20:45:49.060050 2017] [pagespeed:error] [pid 31223:tid 112490802050816] [mod_pagespeed 1.11.33.4-0 @31223] Serf status 120171(APR does not understand this error code) polling for 1 threaded fetches for 0.05 seconds
[Mon Jul 03 20:45:49.060071 2017] [pagespeed:error] [pid 31223:tid 112490802050816] [mod_pagespeed 1.11.33.4-0 @31223] Serf status 120171(APR does not understand this error code) polling for 1 threaded fetches for 0.05 seconds
[Mon Jul 03 20:45:49.910183 2017] [pagespeed:warn] [pid 31225:tid 112490799363840] [mod_pagespeed 1.11.33.4-0 @31225] Fetch timed out: https://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 (connecting to:139.xx.xx.xx:82) (1) waiting for 50 ms
```

Not sure whats going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to understand the cache flow when using both varnish and page_speed.

Please check the link bellow for details:
https://www.sonassi.com/help/troubleshooting/understanding-cache-flow-when-using-pagespeed-and-varnish

Clear all page_speed cache and varnish cache, then restart both varnish and apache.